# Glyphicons not precompiled in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, glyphicons

I am writing a Rails 4 app using Twitter bootstrap (the sass version, with files copied directly into my assets directory rather than using a gem). Glyphicons work in development but in production are displayed as squares. I believe this is because they are not being appropriately precompiled and delivered by the asset pipeline.

I have tried adding the following to production.rb without success:

```
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you included the relative glyph `css` files in your `production.rb` -> `config.assets.precompile += ["layout/fonts/fonts.css"]` ?

Comment: which assets directory? lib/assets, vendor/assets or app/assets?

Comment: "I believe" is not a good starting point for figuring out what is wrong. what is your browser saying about that, do you get 404s in the developer console when loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having difficulties is because your regular expression does not actually match the path names of your fonts. One way going about this is to change your regular expression to match the full path.

```ruby
config.assets.precompile << /.+\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/i
```

On the other hand, regular expressions are not always very readable for other users diving in to your code base and can easily get out of hand. In this case we can a more apt tool for the job, the glob syntax

```ruby
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf )
```